# Use "Find" to select all those cells and the ones directly underneath them

Tags: excel

I have a huge dataset and need all the names. Their are cells that say "Name" and then under it is the name. There is no pattern in when a name shows up. Can I use the "Find" tool to select all "Name" cells and the cells right under them?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't probably needs a vba solution.

Comment: yeah, you can use vba loop through your data and find each occurrence of name and use offset(1,0) to grab the cell.value from the row beneath the cell you find name.

Answer (score 0):

i put sample data on sheet 1 in pic below.  this code will loop through and find each cell with the value "Name" and grab the value from the cell beneath it and enter it on to sheet 2 as in pic 2.

[image: sample data on sheet1]

[image: results listed on sheet2]

```
Sub findName()

Dim i As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress

i = 1

With Worksheets(1).Cells

  Set c = .Find("Name")
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
          Worksheets(2).Range("A" & i).Value = c.Offset(1, 0).Value
          i = i + 1
          Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```